# Error while working with Multi Tenant SAP Cloud Platform application

Tags: java, jpa, odata, sap-cloud-platform

I am working with multi tenant application in SAP Cloud Platform. I am getting an error when fetching the tenant details:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast class
>   com.sap.cloud.account.impl.TenantContextImpl to interface
>   com.sap.cloud.account.TenantContext (found matching interface
>   com.sap.cloud.account.TenantContext loaded by com.sap.cloud.account

Code that causes the issue:

```
public class TenantContextManager
{

public TenantContextManager() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public String getCurrentAccountId() throws ServletException {
    String currentAccountId;        
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        TenantContext tenantctx = (TenantContext) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/TenantContext");                

        currentAccountId = tenantctx.getTenant().getAccount().getId();                  

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }               
    return currentAccountId;        
}
}
```

I am calling an instance of this call in an "`ODataJPAServiceFactory`" class implementation.

A point to note is that I created a simple JSP application and the same code is working correctly.

Comment: Ich arbeite zur Zeit ebenfalls an einer Multi Tenant SAP Cloud Platform application und verwende ein Java Servlet hierzu. Eingebunden habe Ich das über die .WAR Datei in die SCP: Ich bekomme jedoch immer den Statuscode 500 wenn ich diese codezeile verwende : TenantContext tenantContext = (TenantContext) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/TenantContext");

Comment: Vielleich haben Sie eine Idee woran das liegen kann.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue. I changed the runtime from Java Web to Java EE 6 Web Profile. Looks like the API is not available in Java Web.